# Webpack ERROR in resolving fallback for shared module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-context, webpack-module-federation, craco

I have a folder structure as below.
To summarize, it is to implement Module Federation (Host and Child module) and in this case, I am using a shared module (inside shared-context which is just for React Context API object)

```
mymfe
    shared-context
        src
            index.js
            mySharedDataContext.js
        package.json
    my-host-ui
        my-web
            craco.config.js
            modulefederation.config.js
            package.json
            src
                App.js
```

My "shared-context" module only has a Context API object which is re-exported and I want to consume the same in my-host-ui

So in the "shared-context"'s index.js, I am re-exporting the Context API object which I want to consume in App.js as below

```
export {default as MySharedDataContextProvider} from "./mySharedDataContext"
```

And mySharedDataContext.js is a standard Context API hook as below;

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
export const MySharedDataContext = React.createContext();
export default ({children}) => {
    const [mySharedData, setMySharedData] = useState({});
    return (
        <MySharedDataContext.Provider value={[mySharedData, setMySharedData]}>
            {children}
        </MySharedDataContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Now coming to **HOST** module configurations. I have the following configs;

craco.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    static: 'src',
    hot: true,
    port: 3000
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'shared-context': path.resolve(__dirname, '../../shared-context'),
    },
  },
  plugins:[
    {
      plugin: require('./config/craco-federation')
    },
  ]
};
```

craco-federation.js is as below

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const paths = require("react-scripts/config/paths");
const ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin = require("external-remotes-plugin");

const getModuleFederationConfigPath = (additionalPaths = []) => {
  const path = require("path");
  const fs = require("fs");
  const appDirectory = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd());
  const resolveApp = (relativePath) => path.resolve(appDirectory, relativePath);

  const moduleFederationConfigFiles = [
    "modulefederation.config.js",
    ...additionalPaths,
  ];
  return moduleFederationConfigFiles
    .map(resolveApp)
    .filter(fs.existsSync)
    .shift();
};

module.exports = {
  overrideWebpackConfig: ({ webpackConfig, pluginOptions }) => {
    const moduleFederationConfigPath = getModuleFederationConfigPath();

    if (moduleFederationConfigPath) {
      webpackConfig.output.publicPath = "auto";

      if (pluginOptions?.useNamedChunkIds) {
        webpackConfig.optimization.chunkIds = "named";
      }

      const htmlWebpackPlugin = webpackConfig.plugins.find(
        (plugin) => plugin.constructor.name === "HtmlWebpackPlugin"
      );

      htmlWebpackPlugin.userOptions = {
        ...htmlWebpackPlugin.userOptions,
        publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
        excludeChunks: [require(moduleFederationConfigPath).name],
      };

      webpackConfig.plugins = [
        ...webpackConfig.plugins,
        new webpack.container.ModuleFederationPlugin(
          require(moduleFederationConfigPath)
        ),
        new ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin(),
      ];
    }
    return webpackConfig;
  }
};
```

modulefederation.config.js

```
const { dependencies } = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  name: "host",
  remotes: {
    childMfe: "childMfe@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js"
  },
  filename: "remoteEntry.js",
  shared: {
    ...dependencies,
    react: {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: dependencies['react'],
    },
    'react-dom': {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: dependencies['react-dom'],
    },
    'shared-context': {
        import: 'shared-context',
        requiredVersion: require('../../shared-context/package.json').version,
    }
  }
};
```

And in the App.js, I am trying to import as below

```
import MySharedDataContextProvider from 'shared-context';
function App() {
return (
    <MySharedDataContextProvider>
    </MySharedDataContextProvider>
}
```

When I am trying to build, I am getting the below error.

```
ERROR in resolving fallback for shared module shared-context
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'shared-context' in 'C:\mfe\my-host-ui\my-web\src'
```

Not sure what is the correct way to import the shared context.